# How to use where in in Prisma?

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I have made a query below that search user using two columns. But it seems not working properly, I assume it is querying the `where` clause in each column instead of both columns.

Is there a way we could `where ~ in` for two or more columns?

```
const users = [
  {
    user_id: 1,
    school_id: 11,
    ..
  },
  {
    user_id: 2,
    school_id: 22
  },
  ..
]

await prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    AND: {
      user_id: {
        in: users.map(user => user.user_id)
      },
      school_id: {
        in: users.map(user => user.school_id)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The problem it does not search for *both* `user_id` and `school_id`. Instead it search *either* of the two column. I will ask assistance of you guys, or do you have better approach with the same result. thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think the `AND` option works if you send an object. It typically takes an array of objects (https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#examples-46).

The simpler way to do the query is to leave out the `AND` entirely:

```js
await prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    user_id: {
      in: users.map(user => user.user_id)
    },
    school_id: {
      in: users.map(user => user.school_id)
    }
  }
})
```

This is essentially an 'implicit' `AND`.